# How to show custom line direction inside UIlabel of UITableViewCell with better performance

Tags: ios, uilabel, telegram, direction

I want to show some text inside `UIlabel` of a `UITableViewCell` for each cell. Inside the text, for each line of a text,line direction  should displayed correctly. So if the line language is arabic it should be RTL and if it's english it should be LTR. I don't want detect line seperator in `cellForRow` delegate and then build `NSAttributedString` because detection in `cellForRow` has low performance and I have a huge table with huge texts.
How can solve this scenario with good performance?
I also don't know how `Telegram` solve this problem, if anyone know tell me please. Any help appreciated.
**Edit:** Each text that inserted inside UILabel can have different lines that each line can has different language. So for each line I need different direction. Inside UILabel or UITextView I just can set direction for total text not each line of text.

Comment: UILabel should automatically handle RTL/LTR language.  Have you tried it? What problem are you having with what iOS does automatically?

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thanks for reply. Yes it should automatically do it. I can show correct directions with detection of line seperations inside cellForRow and then I can create NSMutableAttributedString that include several lines (each one as  NSAttributedString with correct direction), but as I said I think it has low performance for my huge table and huge texts. So I want a better scenario or if anyone know how Telegram scenario for this problem because it shows correct directions.

Comment: Why do you need to detect line separations?  Perhaps you should be using `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`?  Why isn't the system laying out your text automatically?  If you want  multi-line label, have you set lines to 0?

Comment: I need detection because I need detect each line and then create NSAttributedString with correct direction from it. I set it's line numbers to 0. If it is necessary I change UILabel with UITextView although it needs changes in project. Let me test it with UITextView.

Comment: You keep saying you need to set the correct direction in the `NSAttributedString` - Why?  If your app is running in a RTL locale then iOS will render it RTL; You can test by launching your app with the RTL pseudo language.

Comment: Maybe I don't mention clearly. Each text that inserted inside UILabel can have different lines that each line can has different language. So for each line I need different direction. Inside UILabel or UITextView I just can set direction for total text not each line of text.

Comment: Ok, so that is a pretty significant detail you omitted from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons, it is always advisable to pre-process your data into [NSAttributedStrings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmutableparagraphstyle), for [RTL (line by line)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nswritingdirection) -  and put it into your table-backing array, before you call `reloadData()`.

`cellForRow` should *process minimal data*. `cellForRow` should only be used to *choose* which data to show, depending on the logic. Such as picking it from Array 1 or Array 2 depending upon some UI state that user is in, such as searching mode / collapse-expand mode / language 1-language 2 data etc.

This data itself should be pre-processed as much as possible, and must be rendered readily. As soon as you are done processing, call `reloadData` to render it as-is.